# Indian having UK visa. Can I get a Schengen visa on arrival at France?

Tags: visas, schengen, uk, france, international-travel

I am Indian travelling to UK with a business visa.

I plan to travel to France for a day or two, while I am in UK through Euro Tunnel.

Can I get a Schegan visa on arrival at France?

How much does it cost?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you cannot. Apart from very specific circumstances, visas must be obtained in advance from your country of usual residence.