# Indian citizen living in United Kingdom wants to get a Schengen visa for France

Tags: visas, schengen, uk, france, international-travel

I am an Indian living in UK with a valid UK business visa. I learnt that it is not possible to get a France on-arrival visa from [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43642/indian-having-uk-visa-can-i-get-a-schengen-visa-on-arrival-at-france).

Can I walk in to the French embassy in UK and apply for a Schengen visa using my Indian passport?

Comment: One option: do it and see, then return here and tell us. :)

Comment: Are you on a 'business visa' that was issued for more than 6 months in duration? And more than 3 months unspent leave?

Comment: Exactly what UK visa do you have?

Comment: @MichaelHampton: It is a business visa valid for 6 months :)

Comment: @GayotFow: It is a `business visa` with validity of 6 months. I plan to go to france `only on weekend`. I have `3 more months of validity`

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. That means you cannot qualify as a UK resident under Schengen rules.  France does not offer discretionary latitude on this point, so you need to find another Schengen member to make your application.  Or apply remotely in India.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you cannot apply for a Schengen visa in London.

[Among other requirements](http://www.ambafrance-uk.org/How-and-where-to-apply-for-a-visa):

> To apply for a visa from the French Authorities in London:
>
> - You must be resident in the UK
>
> Your UK residency must have at least 3 months validity after the
>   intended date of departure from the Schengen area. As per the decree
>   2008-1176 of the 13th of November 2008, the French Consulate, London,
>   is not competent in processing visa applications of people not
>   resident in the UK, i.e. holders of ’C-Visit’ visas or of a British
>   visa valid for 6 months or less. People who are not resident in the UK
>   must apply for their Schengen visas at the French Consulate in their
>   country of residence.

Comment: The OP clearly stated that he is an indian living in UK, so this should not be a problem, right?

Comment: He said he's on a business visa. While I do have a US mindset, that implies to me non-resident. Perhaps it's a work visa instead. Gayot Fow has asked the OP about the visa length.

Comment: Well, perhaps. He said he's living there on a working visa, I supposed it's not a temporary work, but a permanent one. The answer to Gayot Fow comment will clear that up.

Comment: @mkennedy: It is a business visa valid for 6 months